# MPAndroidChart not scrolling

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using PhilJay/MPAndroidChart and I have 12 Entries on X axis but i want show 6 at a time and rest could be visible on scroll to right. I have tried

```
mChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(6);
```

chart shows 6 entries but it is not scrolling to last entry .

I tried [this answer also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41117959/6880632)

Comment: Can you please show complete code regarding your chart configurations. Because this should work there is something else causing issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Overall, you definitely need to provide more info, like the way you initialize, configure your chart and the way you have it in your layout. However, on top of my head you could try with this:

1. Use `yourChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter` to make sure you have needed labels on x
2. Set label count like this `yourChart.getXAxis().setLabelCount`
3. Set needed granularity like this `yourChart.getXAxis().setGranularity` (and enable it `yourChart.getXAxis().setGranularityEnabled`)
4. Fit the chart to screen `yourChart.fitScreen`

Last but not least, you may need to play with `yourChart.setScaleMinima` if data item count grows.

Update: to display last section of the chart, use `yourChart.centerViewTo(barChart.getXChartMax(), 0, YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT)` AFTER you set data.